# How to write appropriate numbers in non of math, physics and chemistry sites in stackexchange?

Tags: support, feature-request, mathjax

in my question in my ell.stackexchange account, I want that look like user$20445$ instead of user20445.

How can I do this? I am not comfortable with these inappropriate numbers.[image]

Comment: I wonder if Unicode has different types of numerals... user➀➄➁➄➈ I did find this.  But note: if you use some special way to write your username (such as MathJax), then we cannot talk to you by clicking on it or copying it... The result `user$20445$` does not refer to you, user20445 .

Comment: @GEdgar you see 15259? How?

Comment: 15259 was just a sample, using those numerals in circles.

Comment: Because you seem to be asking about how to change the appearance of your(?) username on StackExchange sites other than this one, I've vote to close as off-topic.  That said, the Question does not seem to state a clear issue about which one might get support.

Answer (score 5):

The numbers are not inappropriate. This is a standard font. You can change the font on your side, if you want to. Of course basically everybody else will still see it differently. Some instructions are here [How to change all fonts on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300905/how-to-change-all-fonts-on-stack-exchange-sites)

You should not use MathJax here for writing these numbers either. That is inappropriate. You should use MathJax only for Mathematics.